# SVM Algorithm is my model valid

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am having a dataset, a large dataset . I plotted the data using T-SNE , I could not find a linear separable decision boundary, Since I could not found a decision boundary in it .

I tried SVM and hoped that It would work , if it able to separate the hyper plane in higher dimension.

Currently I am getting an training accuracy of 94% but i had received  testing error of 50% later on when I increased the size of the dataset by 20,000 entries the accuracy of training data increased to 65% (which is also , more or less same in cross validation) , training accuracy is still 93%.
 My question is , Am I actually solving this machine learning problem accurately ? or am I in a wrong direction and If possible can some one please provide me some link regarding to a practical approach to solving problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the data. Basically your SVM is memorising the training data and fails to predict correctly for new data it has not seen before. You can try to decrease overfitting by using a smaller `C`.

I think in general it is hard to say if SVM is the correct approach for your problem. There is the [no free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) which postulates that there probably isn't a single machine learning algorithm for solving all problems and I am currently not aware of any way to map problems to their optimal algorithms.

You probably should fix the obvious errors in the current approach using the SVM and then study where and why it fails. If you have done this you might be able to choose another algorithm that can address those shortcomings.

Comment: Thanks for your information siestschie. I will  try to add more data to the, current problem, then will try grid search of sklearn library . Will see how svm performs. Depending on that I will see if SVM performs well in the current situation or will switch to different algorithm , after learning what cause the following problem issue. Thanks for your suggestion.